# Display summation of columns in the footer of jqxgrid

Tags: jqxgrid

I need to display a footer row at the very bottom of the Jqxgrid, in which sum of the columns in the grid should get dynamically calculated as and when the values of the columns are getting in the grid.

I am using a Keyboard Navigation Jqxgrid which is being present in the following link 'http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/rowdetails.htm'. I checked out the API references for the same to try out this, but dint get any fruitful results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample with Grid Aggregates: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/aggregates.htm?classic

Comment: Thank you so very much, it works like a charm. Actually i was trying with the aggregates as well, but since I am working on this for the first time, i was doing trial and errors with this. I had missed these two properties, because of which i did not get the result: showstatusbar: true, statusbarheight: 50. Rest all of the aggregates settings i had done.